# Enable Undo CoreData SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

Does anyone know how to have the **Undo** command in the menu bar **enable** when **CoreData** UndoManager has items to undo?

Here’s what I’ve done:

- At app init I’m setting the Core Data PersistanceController UndoManager()

  *persistenceController.container.viewContext.undoManager = UndoManager()*
- I can confirm the CoreData undoManager is set because I can programmatically call undo and it works (for instance after deletion)
- HOWEVER the Undo command in the menuBar remains disabled.

*As a side-note, the Undo command in the menuBar works correctly when I’m writing text in a TextField (it does automatically enable to undo text changes).*

Huge thanks in advance, been trying things for a while and can’t find anything online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context is not clear, but try (just an idea) to use Undo Manager from environment, like

```
// ... somewhere in view where you change core data objects

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
@Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager

// ...

var body: some View {
  // ...
  .onAppear {
     viewContext.undoManager = undoManager
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what did it, thanks Asperi!